# A problem in loading index.php

Tags: theme-development

Instead of loading index.php, my page.php is loading.I cannot understand the problem.Please help me.The body of the content is not displaying.

Comment: You have set static home page from `settings ->Reading` menu ?

Comment: yes i have set static home page to reading menu

Comment: will you please help me?

Comment: Your issue solved OR not?

Answer (score 0):

WordPress is doing exactly what you're telling it to do, based on the [Template Hierarchy](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy) and your Reading Settings.

The first thing to understand is that WordPress uses **`index.php`** as the *default fallback template file* for all contexts, and *not* as the *site front page template*.

The second thing to understand is that the template file WordPress uses to display the **site front page** depends on your Reading Settings:

- If the current Theme includes a **`front-page.php`** template file, WordPress will use it, regardless of Reading Settings. Otherwise:
- If your front page is set to display a **static page**, then WordPress uses the [**Page Hierarchy**](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy#Page_display) to display the site front page:

  - `_wp_page_template` (custom page template)
  - `page-{slug}.php`
  - `page-{id}.php`
  - `page.php`
  - `index.php`
- If your front page is set to display the **blog posts index**, then WordPress uses the [**Home Page Hierarchy**](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy#Home_Page_display) to display the site front page:

  - `home.php`
  - `index.php`

The third thing to understand is that, regardless of template file used, if your Reading Settings are set to display the **blog posts index** on the site front page, then the **default query** on the site front page will be the *default blog posts query*; but if your Reading Settings are set to display a **static page** on the site front page, then the **default query** will be for the *static page assigned to the front page*. That means that, even if you have the front page set to display a static page, and the Page Hierarchy falls back to `index.php`, then `index.php` is still only going to display a loop of one post: the static page assigned to the front page.